# Pulling multiple excel values for VBA SQL query Where

Tags: sql, vba, parameters

I am looking to create import multiple cell values (order numbers) into a SQL query.

I have been able to write the code and it works for only 1 cell value.

For example, the code below pulls the order number from cell D4 into the where clause -and it works, however I am looking to pull from D4 to DXX.

So it would be 20 or 100 order numbers to pull in the where clause.

I searched for hours and could not find a solution.

I feel like I'm so close.. yet so far.

It is the STRDATA string I need help with.

Also, under the where clause, I think instead of Field = order number, it needs to be Field in (order number1, order number2, order number3)

Thank you

```
Sub Import()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Strdata As String

    Strdata = Worksheets("Loan Level").Range("D4").Value
    Server_Name = " "
    Database_Name = ""
    User_ID = ""
    Password = ""
    SQLStr = "SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLES WHERE FIELD= '" & Strdata & "'"

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    With Worksheets("sheet1").Range("a1:z500")
        .ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `IN` would be better here.

You can build up the string variable by looking at each cell in the range.
This assumes that each cell has a valid entry.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim sWHEREclause As String
    Dim SQLStr As String

    Set rRange = Sheet1.Range("D4:DXX4")

    For Each rCell In rRange
        sWHEREclause = sWHEREclause & "'" & rCell & "',"
    Next rCell

    'Remove the last comma.
    sWHEREclause = Left(sWHEREclause, Len(sWHEREclause) - 1)

    SQLStr = "SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLES WHERE FIELD IN (" & sWHEREclause & ")"

    Debug.Print SQLStr

End Sub
```

This will build an SQL string as (I've shortened the range of cells):
`SELECT FIELDS FROM TABLES WHERE FIELD IN ('A','B','C','D','E','F')`